# New Emacs primitive does not show up

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote a new Emacs primitive (macroexpand-once) and recompiled Emacs

Now `(macroexpand-once)` fails with "Symbol's function definition is void".

What do I do about this?

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
DEFUN ("macroexpand-once", Fmacroexpand_once, Smacroexpand_once, 1, 2, 0,
       doc: /* Return result of expanding macros at top level of FORM.
               If FORM is not a macro call, it is returned unchanged.
               Otherwise, the macro is expanded and the expansion is returned.
               The second optional arg ENVIRONMENT specifies an environment of macro
               definitions to shadow the loaded ones for use in file byte-compilation.  */)
     (Lisp_Object form, Lisp_Object environment)
{
  /* With cleanups from Hallvard Furuseth.  */
  register Lisp_Object expander, sym, def, tem;

  do
    {
      /* Come back here each time we expand a macro call,
     in case it expands into another macro call.  */
      if (!CONSP (form))
    break;
      /* Set SYM, give DEF and TEM right values in case SYM is not a symbol. */
      def = sym = XCAR (form);
      tem = Qnil;
      /* Trace symbols aliases to other symbols
     until we get a symbol that is not an alias.  */
      while (SYMBOLP (def))
    {
      QUIT;
      sym = def;
      tem = Fassq (sym, environment);
      if (NILP (tem))
        {
          def = XSYMBOL (sym)->function;
          if (!EQ (def, Qunbound))
        continue;
        }
      break;
    }
      /* Right now TEM is the result from SYM in ENVIRONMENT,
     and if TEM is nil then DEF is SYM's function definition.  */
      if (NILP (tem))
    {
      /* SYM is not mentioned in ENVIRONMENT.
         Look at its function definition.  */
      struct gcpro gcpro1;
      GCPRO1 (form);
      def = Fautoload_do_load (def, sym, Qmacro);
      UNGCPRO;
      if (EQ (def, Qunbound) || !CONSP (def))
        /* Not defined or definition not suitable.  */
        break;
      if (!EQ (XCAR (def), Qmacro))
        break;
      else expander = XCDR (def);
    }
      else
    {
      expander = XCDR (tem);
      if (NILP (expander))
        break;
    }
      {
    Lisp_Object newform = apply1 (expander, XCDR (form));
    if (EQ (form, newform))
      break;
    else
      form = newform;
      }
    } while (0);
  return form;
}
```

It is just the code of `macroexpand`, but with do-while(0) instead of while(1).

Comment: We will need to see the code you wrote to have any chance of helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `defsubr`.  Do a search for `Smacroexpand` to see what I mean.